# Thermally activated delayed fluorescence

Tags: quantum-spin, spectroscopy, photon-emission, fluorescence

In thermally activated delayed fluorescent (TADF) molecules, we consider 25% molecules in singlet first excited state and 75% in triplet, statistically, on electrical excitation after carrier injection ( for organic molecules). What would be the ratio if no carrier injection is done and we are performing photo excitation? Should the 75% molecules still go to triplet (it is a forbidden state) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have two states with roughly similar energies you would expect roughly equal occupancy of the two states i.e. 50% occupation of both.

However a triplet state behaves (as the name suggests) as three states with $S_z = +1$, $0$ and $-1$. So when you have a singlet state and a triplet state with roughly equal energies you get four different states, each with roughly 25% occupation, one of them the singlet and the other three the triplet. That's why we find 75% of the electrons in the triplet state and 25% in the singlet.

This is a general result that doesn't depend on the exact details as long as the states have roughly equal energies and there is a way for electrons to transition between the states. In TADF molecules the transitioning between the states is due to thermal energy i.e. interactions of the electrons with the lattice.

Comment: I understand the statistics that 25% will go to singlet and 75% to triplet. My question is 75% should not go to triplet since the transition is forbidden whether going up or coming down, inter system crossing is forbidden for organic molecules as they don't have large extent of spin-orbit coupling or any other means. My doubt is that 25% should be in the exited singlet state while triplet should not be accessible due to its forbidden nature. Why is that accessible? That's my real question as we do get more than 25% quantum yield of TADF molecules.

Comment: @AjeetSingh Singlet to triplet optical transitions are allowed because the photon has spin one. It's the singlet to singlet transitions that are forbidden. But in the solid state pretty much everything is allowed as the electrons can exchange energy and angular momentum with the lattice.

Comment: As far as I know, singlet to triplet transitions are forbidden as they require change in spin. Total spin multiplicity should remain same initially and after transition and singlet to triplet transition means multiplicity is changing.

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: transition from singlet to triplet is forbidden as the selection rule states that spin multiplicity should not change. This rule can be overcome if we perturb our system via some coupling. In solid state, spin change is allowed due to lattice. But in the given question, i am talking about solution phase and organic molecules. So neither we have any coupling or lattice to account for spin change.

Comment: Thanks anyway,a nice discussion always bring out something good